# Agrupar datas que estão no MySQL em PHP

Tags: php, mysql, data

Tenho uma tabela em MySQL chamada `apartamento_data`, nela existem datas que o apartamento está alugado, ou seja, indisponível para alugar. Cada linha uma data, assim:

> ```
> 2017-05-31
> 2017-06-01
> 2017-06-04
> 2017-06-05
> 2017-06-06
> ```

O que preciso, fazer uma consulta e listar essas datas agrupadas por período, ou seja, pego os dias que são consecutivos e listo apenas o primeiro e o último, no exemplo acima ficaria assim:

> ```
> de 2017-05-31 até 2017-06-01 
> de 2017-06-04 até 2017-06-06
> ```

Como fazer isso via PHP? Minha consulta está assim:

```
SELECT apartamento_data.data_locado FROM apartamento
LEFT JOIN apartamento_data ON apartamento.id = partamento_data.idapartamento
WHERE apartamento.id=:qualApartamento
ORDER BY apartamento_data.data_locado ASC
```

Mas acredito que eu tenha que fazer essa tratamento das datas no PHP, dentro do `foreach`, certo?

Comment: precisa quebrar por mês? de qualquer forma, poste sua consulta atual pra ajudar ;)

Comment: Por quê 6 datas ficaram apenas 4? Por serem períodos contínuos? Não seria conveniente criar colunas "data_inicio" e "data_fim" ao invés de cadastrá-las em linhas distintas?

Comment: Opa, editei a pergunta, tinha escrito errado. @AndersonCarlosWoss seria sim, mas o banco não é meu, é do cliente, apenas estou fazendo essa consulta para gerar um XML

Comment: Interessante sua pergunta, mas tenho uma duvida, a data de inicio e fim da locação estão em linhas distintas?

Comment: @WeesSmith sim. Cada linha da tabela uma data. Essa é grande dificuldade. Preciso saber quando a diferença entre elas é maior q um dia e tratar (saber quando é maior que um dia eu sei fazer)

Comment: Eu ainda não entendi essas datas rsrs, se eu reservar um apartamento por três dias, o o banco terá três registros, um para cada dia? Isso?

Comment: @IpFranz isso mesmo!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acabei conseguindo, talvez não seja a forma ideal e mais eficaz, mas funcionou, segue o código comentado, se tiverem dúvidas é só perguntar:

```
    $sql = $pdo->prepare('SELECT apartamento_data.data_locado FROM apartamento
        LEFT JOIN apartamento_data ON apartamento.id = apartamento_data.idapartamento
        WHERE apartamento.ativo = "1" AND apartamento.flipkey = "1" AND apartamento.id=:qualApartamento
        ORDER BY apartamento_data.data_locado ASC');
    $sql->execute(array("qualApartamento" => $qual));
    $resultadoSql_Apartamento = $sql->fetchAll();
    $totalConsulta = count($resultadoSql_Apartamento);
    //
    $data_compara = "2000-00-00"; // setei uma data inicial bem antiga para comparação inicial (a primeira data sempre será a data inicial)
    $primeira_consulta = 1; // variável para saber se é a primeira consulta
    $conta_consultas = 1;
    $ultima_consulta = 0; // varíavel para saber se a última data chegou
    foreach($resultadoSql_Apartamento as $valorSql) {
        $data_locado = utf8_encode($valorSql['data_locado']);
        //
        // checa se a diferença dentre as datas é maior que 1 dia
        $diferenca = strtotime($data_locado) - strtotime($data_compara);
        $diferenca = floor($diferenca / (60 * 60 * 24));
        //
        // se a diferença for maior que um, ou seja, não é consecutiva)
        if($diferenca != 1){
            // se for a primeira consulta (uso para o sistema não listar a data final da primeira sequencia de dias antes da primeira)
            if($primeira_consulta == 1){
                $primeira_consulta = 2;
                // listo a data inicial
                echo "de ".$data_locado." até ";
            }else{
                // listo a data final (pego a variável $data_compara que é só aliemntada no final do loop)
                echo $data_compara."<br>";
                // digo que chegou a última data
                $ultima_consulta = 1;
                // listo a data inicial (uma nova sequencia sempre se incia se não for a última data)
                if($totalConsulta > $conta_consultas){
                    echo "de ".$data_locado." até ";
                    $primeira_consulta = 2;
                    // digo que na verdade não chegou na última data
                    $ultima_consulta = 0;
                }
            }
        }
        //
        $data_compara = $data_locado;
        $conta_consultas++;
    }
    // mostro a última data
    if($ultima_consulta == 0){
        echo $data_locado;
    }
```